# Two query methods give different results

Tags: mysql, sql

I am two days into MySQL.  While working on a database of movies, I decided to try and answer a specific question: what movies from a list of 1000 made a negative profit, but had an IMDB score between 8 and 9?

Ideally, I wanted to return only a list of movies that meet that criteria, but at first, I had not known the `WHERE` statement.  So I used `CASE`, so that I could simply mark those movies with `'Quality Anomaly'`.
Then, when I learned about `WHERE`, I implemented it.  However, the results were different.  The query using `CASE` only marked 6 movies, and the query using `WHERE` returned 51 movies (rows).  I added the appropriate columns so I could check to make sure it was right, and it all checked out, but there is something weird.  When I do a query of `SELECT *`, to return all movies, there are many missing from the complete list of 1000 that are in the list of 51 from the query using `WHERE`.
Here is the code:

/** 
This query is supposed to return all movie titles while indicating
the profit from the movie, or 'Quality Anomaly' if profit is
negative while imdb score is between 8 and 9.  It only indicates
'Quality Anomaly' for 6 movies. 
**/

```
select
    movie_title,
    imdb_score,
    case
        when (gross < budget) and (imdb_score between 8 and 9) then 'Quality Anomaly'
        else gross - budget
    end as profit
from movies;
​
```

/**
The next query is supposed to only list the movies that meet
the `'Quality Anomaly'` condition described above, but instead
of returning only 6 movies, it returns 51.
**/

```
select
    movie_title,
    (gross - budget) as profit,
    imdb_score
from movies
where (gross < budget) and (imdb_score between 8 and 9);
```

[Link to output data via github.](https://github.com/CpInCpp/MySQL_movies_db.git)

Comment: Your first query returns all the rows; your second filters the rows.  That is why they return different numbers of rows.

Comment: As @GordonLinoff said, a `case when` is not a filter, but a new column in your resultset

Comment: Yes.  I don't think I was clear.  The first query returns 1000 rows, but only marks 6 rows with the condition met.  The second query returns 51 rows with the condition met, but only six of those are the ones marked in the first query.  Furthermore, some (if not all) of the remaining 45 rows from the second query are not in the first query of 1000 rows.  AND they are not returned in a query of all rows from the db.

Comment: Please attach sample data reproducing your output anomally.

Comment: @KamilGosciminski Post has been updated to include a link to output data, and to fix the spelling of 'anomaly.'

Comment: Your IDE applies LIMIT (1000 rows) to queries to avoid program freeze in case of huge chunk of data. Try to execute these queries in `mysql` command line utility.

Comment: Btw - your case statement is returning different types depending on conditions: a string value *Quality Anomaly* and numerical calculation `gross - budget`. Strange MySQL allows this possibly with implicit casting.

Comment: @VadimAshikhman That was it.  I changed the limit settings in the IDE and found that there were actually 4916 rows.  Thank you.